# how to add custom select field to wordpress edit page

Tags: php, functions

[image]

I would like to add a checkbox field to the menu on the right,
I googled it but i cant seem to find anything on it, just wondering if anyone has anything on it

Comment: Do you mean on the far right under Document? That is the Inspector sidebar. It depends on what you want the checkbox to do - you can add custom taxonomies or metaboxes that appear there as checkboxes, or if you want something completely different you could look into SlotFills.

Comment: the expanding and contracting parts are called panels, searching for how to add panels to the block editor will give more useful results

Answer (score 0):

A legacy solution is to [`add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) and set its context as `side`. This makes the custom metabox visible in the block editor Document sidebar.

The modern way is to add a custom [panel](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/panel/) with [Block API](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/).

Or if you've registered a custom taxonomy with [`register_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/), then you need to have `show_in_rest` parameter set to `true` to make it visible in the block editor.